# Intellij doesn't prompt to import androidx.compose

Tags: intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a Kotlin multiplatform project.  On a unresolvable symbol like "Modifier", I press ALT + ENTER, then Intellij prompts me to import from a few sources but not including androidx.compose.ui.  I wonder why?

Update: Though somewhat confusing at the UI, I created "Kotlin Multiplatform" -> "Compose Multiplatform Application" project.  So it's JVM based.  In commonMain there is the @Composable fun app().

It seems ALT+ENTER doesn't work on all compose symbols.  If I manually import the symbol, say Modifier, then after I type Modifier.padd it prompts for completion, and if I hit Tab to accept a completion (padding for instance), then padding is automatically imported.  If I didn't accept the completion suggestion, and later type Alt+Enter on padding, then there is no prompt for import.

Comment: Have you created Compose multiplatform project? Mobile KMM project is targeted to iOS which means Compose cannot be used in common module - it only supports Desktop and Android so far.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest [Compose Multiplatform IDE Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16541-compose-multiplatform-id) plugin installed. If this doesn't help, I suggest you [report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) this issue, as from what you say it looks like related to IDEA.

Comment: I have that latest plugin.  Reported an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292333